# Powershell Script : compare outputs from tables (get-adorganizationalunits)

Tags: powershell, active-directory

This is my first post and I'm completely new at this, so I'd like to keep this as simple as possible.

---

Purpose:

- Search domain for an OU
- If it exists -> Tell me it exists
- If it is missing -> Create an OU with that name

---

#This is how far I've got:

```
clear-host
$search = Read-host "Which OU are you looking for?"

#Get all of the OUs in a domain
$all_ous=Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Filter 'Name -like "*"' | Format-Table Name -A -HideTableHeaders

#Get an OU by its distinguished name
$a_ou=Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Identity "OU=search,DC=firstdomain,DC=local" | Format-Table Name -A -HideTableHeaders


if ($a_ou -in $all_ou) {
        Write-Host "it already exists"
}
else{
new-adorganizationalunit "$search"
```

---

My thoughts: I think `$a_ou` and `$all_ou` are arrays. It says `system.array` when i do "`$all_ou.gettype()`"... I'm not sure if it's possible to compare two arrays in this way.

Do you know a simple way that I can follow with limited knowledge about coding?
Greatly appreciate it

Comment: You're not using your `$Search` variable. Are you intentions to have that be what's compared with the objects returned from `$all_ou`?

Comment: Where are you planning to create the new OUs? Always top level?

Comment: @AbrahamZinala 
$a_ou=Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Identity "OU=$search,DC=firstdomain,DC=local" | Format-Table Name -A -HideTableHeaders

I forgot to add a $ above. Btw sorry about the mess in my post. I must have done a mistake when posting it.

Yes, $search defines the OU that I'm looking for. I want the "identity" of that object to be compared with the root-directory-contents. If it doesn't exist it will be created. 

But the first step is to get the if-statement working. Can you see why it's not working?

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon Yes, top-level

Answer (score 1):

```
# requires -Modules ActiveDirectory

function Search-OU {
[cmdletbinding()]
param(
    [parameter(mandatory)]
    [string]$Name,
    [switch]$Wildcard
)

    begin
    {
        $defNamingContext = (Get-ADRootDSE).defaultNamingContext
    }

    process
    {
        if($Wildcard.IsPresent)
        {
            $ou = Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Filter "Name -like '*$Name*'"
        }
        else
        {
            $ou = Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Filter "Name -eq '$Name'"
        }

        if($ou)
        {
            return 'OU already exists: {0}' -f $ou.DistinguishedName
        }

        New-ADOrganizationalUnit -Name $Name -Path $defNamingContext -PassThru
    }
}
```

#### Usage:

- If you want to search for a OU with a specific name: 
  `Search-OU -Name randomOU`
- If you want a wildcard search for an OU:
  `Search-OU -Name randomOU -Wildcard`